# Remove Subscription Key from Developer Portal -> Try It

Tags: azure-api-management

I am using jwts for authorization instead of subscriptions, so I am trying to remove all traces of the concept of a subscription key.

However, in the developer portal when using the Try It feature, Subscription Key is listed as an input. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Even better, I would like to replace the Subscription key with JWT token.

[Subscription key input I would like to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThfaN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, the fix will be out in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. May I ask how you know this? Is it listed in github or a developer feedback area?

Comment: We are part of the product team and work on this project.

By the way, the release to the managed version of the portal got delayed, and we cannot give you ETA at the moment. So, the fix will land to opens source version only for now.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Product and set it to not require subscription. Any APIs added to that product will not require subscription key to be invoked, i.e. from APIM standpoint they become anonymous, so ensure that you have some authentication in policies, like validate-jwt. In any way, Developer portal should hide subscription key UI for such APIs.

Comment: I did as you said and created a product that didnt require a subscription. In the settings of my api, under products, i added the no subscription product and removed unlimited. Also, subscription required is unchecked. I republished my portal to make sure, but it still lists subscription key when using Try It.